# Native wrappers between HTML pages

Tags: cordova

I understand PhoneGap can give me a wrapped UIWebView that can act like a normal browser - so that following links will just refresh the current UIWebView.

I'm wondering if it's possible to isolate individual pages in their own UIWebView?

That way the window management is handled natively rather than dynamically with Javascript.

For example, I could have an INDEX.HTML that links off to other pages. But I'd want those links to fire up in a fresh native window.